# AttributeError at /api/test type object 'Product' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I get AttributeError at /api/test
type object 'Product' has no attribute 'objects' error when I try to load up the page via get request, I'm trying to make an API using django rest framework and it says Product has no objects attribute.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import ProductSerializer
from .models import Product
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class Product(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        products = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products)
        return Response(serializer)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
# router = routers.DefaultRouter()
# router.register('products', views.ProductViewSet)
# router.register('test', views.Product)
# urlpatterns = router.urls



urlpatterns = [
    path('test', views.Product.as_view())
]
```

serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name','price','description']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the name of view, ProductView because its overriding Product model thats why you are getting this error